# Lie group quotient structure

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a normal finite subgroup. Let $\pi : G \to G/H$ be the quotient surjection. How would one show that $G/H$ is a Lie group?

Comment: What's your difficult? Can you prove that it's a manifold? The group structure part is exactly as in the case of ordinary groups and the differentiability follows directly from the differentiable structure of the quotient.

Comment: So in this case, is H discrete and compact? I am not sure how to prove the manifold aspect, specifically the atlas.

Comment: Yes $H$ is discrete and compact (you need this to proper discontinuity of the action).Try constructing in a natural way an atlas that makes $\pi$ a submersion with fibers diffeomorphic to $H$.

Comment: Anyway, this http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/foliations2006/actions.pdf answer your question in a more general context (but the proof is almost the same).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused. Would you not construct the atlas in the usual way as charts from euclidean space? Where does the fibers of $\pi$ come in?

Comment: Would the additional hypotheses of discreteness and compactness simplify it considerably?

Comment: Yes. The fibers must be transversal to the atlas in $G$. Yes it will simplify, because it will be a covering space (so it's not just locally trivial, it's locally a diffeomorphism), so you define the atlas such that it's pullback is the atlas of $G$. In the general case where $H$ is just normal, you can use Godement theorem or approximate locally by the lie algebra (this is why you need transversality of the fibers).

Comment: would it be possible for you to quickly sketch the proof for $G/H$ being a manifold?

Comment: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/qtmanifold.pdf here it's explained everything